# How to Convert splitted pdf to Excel file using java pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

**Im new to this PDFBOX. I hve one pdf file, which contain 60 pages. Im using Apache PDFBox-app-1.8.10. jar splitting up the PDF files.**

```
public class SplitDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   JButton open = new JButton();
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:/Users"));
fc.setDialogTitle("Select PDF");

if(fc.showOpenDialog(open)== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{

}
String a = null;
a = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
      PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    document = PDDocument.load(a);


    // Create a Splitter object
    Splitter splitter = new Splitter();

    // We need this as split method returns a list
    List<PDDocument> listOfSplitPages;

    // We are receiving the split pages as a list of PDFs
    listOfSplitPages = splitter.split(document);

    // We need an iterator to iterate through them
    Iterator<PDDocument> iterator = listOfSplitPages.listIterator();

    // I am using variable i to denote page numbers. 
    int i = 1;
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        PDDocument pd = iterator.next();
        try{
            // Saving each page with its assumed page no.
            pd.save("G://PDFCopy/Page " + i++ + ".pdf");

        } catch (COSVisitorException anException){
            // Something went wrong with a PDF object
            System.out.println("Something went wrong with page " + (i-1) + "\n Here is the error message" + anException);                
        }  

    }       
}
```

}

**In PDFCopy Folder i hve list of pdf files. How can I convert all pdf to excel format and need to save it in the target folder. i am fully confused in this conversion. **

Comment: There is no magic solution. You're gonna have to extract whatever you need (if it is always at the same position) and then create an Excel file with Apache POI the hard way, i.e. fill every cell.

Comment: Is not possible to convert directly without extracting using Apache PDFbox...??  kindly can u provide me any link for Apache POI for this function...  Im really new to this Java tech

Comment: You can't convert PDF to excel unless you do some guessing. There is no "table" concept in PDF (except for tagged PDFs, but PDFBox doesn't support this much, and I doubt that your invoices have it). Apache POI is at https://poi.apache.org/ . You have to understand that PDF is a graphic format. There is no <TABLE> element like in HTML. What you see as a "table" is just a bunch of lines and texts in no special sequence. If your invoices are all by the same producer, you could use text extraction by area and create cells with what you get.

Comment: ok FIne. Now Im able to read pdf using     Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc).   Ive not saved in it specific location, but i can read this. but I'm nt able to convert it to excel excel.

Comment: In text format my pdf look like dis     (No tables in my PDF)                                                                    No. of Pages : 69
   Sales - Invoice 
   Page 1
   ....... India Pvt Ltd
Datiyar Shimla High Way
Solan
Parwanoo , 173220
Phone No. +91-1792-235
Fax No. +91-1792-
T.I.N. No. 0200021 Invoice No. D0000003010
Order No. SO106818
Original
Employee-2
Fossil
......-Employee
Indiranagar
......., 560008    and so on.....

Comment: You need to read about Apache POI, i.e. understand the API on how to create an empty excel file, and how to assign values to cells. There is no "pdf in, excel out" converter. You need to write all this yourself based on the values you get in text extraction, and it is YOU who decides in what cell the content should be.

Comment: Okay Fine. I vl try it out. Thnks for ur help